# Users with Google Sheet Access unable to use Script Menu add ons

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Very new to coding, tried my best to search Google App forums and stackoverflow for this answer but haven't really gotten a firm answer.

I have a shared Google sheet for a community work schedule. All users have "edit" access to a sheet that is "protected". I have created an addMenu with a few options that would allow users to Export their schedule to their own google calendar they simply enter their calendar id and voila exported boring spreadsheet schedule to personal google calendar. I have ran this 'bound' script flawlessly many times as the owner of the script, now I would like all users whom I have granted access to, to be able to export Sheet info to their personal calendar.

Now I realize there are authorization issues but is there an EASY way for these 20+ invited users to "Authorize" access for the script to run and write in their calendar?

OR...Do I have to give script level access to all of these users individually?

If I need to post the code I will but it's a little on the messy side...works well but Messy....

Comment: Please checkout [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization). Regarding adding code, see [mcve].

Comment: To sum up what Ruben already said: each user will have to give access to the necessary scopes when they first run the script and again if the scopes change.

Comment: Thank you for your help!